# Correct way of accessing a file with name

Tags: java, file, netbeans, file-io, path

Ok I need someone to clear things up for me. 
I saw a hundred different ways of accessing a file to read in it (`FileReader`).

I tried all of them and can't find a way to do it correctly.

If I try :

```
String path = Engine.class.getResource("Words.txt").toString();
```

or

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("Words.txt");
String path = url.getFile();
File myFile = new File(path);
```

I go directly to :

```
dispatchUncaughtException
```

I just don't know where to look anymore since no one seems to agree on the good way to do it. Also, what is that kind of exception ?
There **must** be an easy way to do this since it is such an easy task. I just want my program to see my `Words.txt` file that is in the `SRC` folder of my project.

---

Full code if it helps :

```
public String GetWord()
{
 String [] Words = new String [10];
 int random = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
 URL url = getClass().getResource("Words.txt");
 String path = url.getFile();
 File myFile = new File(path);

  try 
  {
       FileReader myReader = new FileReader(myFile);
       BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(myReader);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           Words[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
   } 
  catch(Exception e) 
  { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }

  return Words[random];
  }
```

Comment: Btw my attempts might not make sense to some of you i'm new to java excuse me for this but I don't know where to look now.

Comment: For clarification, in your program, do you know the full path to the file, or is it something that has to be determined by the program?

Comment: I can't hardcode the full path. The program has to understand that it is in it's Src file.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: In that case, I think what you can do is, get the path to the root of the classpath, go up a directory, and then append the file name to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String path = Engine.class.getResource("Words.txt").toString();
```

For that to work, your file has to be in the same package as the `Engine` class. So, you probably want to move your file to the package where the class is at.

If you want to move the file into some other package then you need to specify the location starting from the root of the classpath. e.g. `/some/other/pkg/Words.txt`.

---

For a file which is not in the classpath, you need the full path along with the file name, to be able to read the file. The `SRC` folder itself is not a package and not in the classpath.

In that case, you can do something as follows:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\path\\to\\file\\Words.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Comment: If his file is sitting in the source folder (I assume outside of any package), I think he could use a file pointer as well, such as `File file = new File('src/Words.txt');`, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right, but it is not needed because we can just create a file input stream, which can be used by a reader.

Comment: Yup, good point. I think I commented at the same time you made your edit.:)  I suppose he could use the file pointer to validate whether the file exists first, etc, if he so desired. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 7 I recommend using [newBufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). It's more efficient and easier to use than the BufferedReader. I also modified your code to match the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

**Working exmaple:**

```
public String getWord() {
    String[] words = new String[10];
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    Path path = Paths.get("src" + System.getProperty("file.separator")
            + "Words.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader textReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            words[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return words[random];
}
```